# How to close a Modern UI Style application in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

Althought I appreciate the Modern UI in Windows 8, I prefer keeping my `Alt+Tab` clear when switching applications when I am developing so I don't potentially hit the wrong application when I am 100% in the zone and in my workflow.

I know I can press `Alt+F4` to close a Modern UI Style application, although this doesn't actually exit it, but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I've noticed they don't terminate immediately with Alt+F4, but after some seconds they will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always taken this neat little shortcut:

Move your mouse to the top of the screen (By where it says app-preview on the microsoft apps). It'll become a hand. Then click and drag all the way to the bottom. The app should be closed.