# How to close apps in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

How to easily exit app on Windows 8? J have a funny problem with "music" and so on (W8 apps in the metro view). There must be faster way then alt+f4 or middle-click on the left panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either close it with the open app view at the left top corner, or just drag the middle top of the app down to the bottom to close an app.