# Close running application Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

Running Metro Apps, there is no Close "X" to click on to end a program.

So How can I exit a running application?

Comment: Metro app or normal app??

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut Alt-F4 still works.

Answer (score 0):

Windows automatically suspends the app when it detects that its no longer in use and the application stops using resources.

However if you want to manually kill the program, move the mouse curser to the top center of the screen, The curser changes to a hand. Click and Drag the curser to the bottom of the screen to end the program.

Alternatively, you can use alt+f4 to end the program.

and lastly, you can use task manager or process explorer to end the program.