# How do you close a metro app that is currently running without switching to a different app first?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

Basically, is there any easy way to quit an application and automatically return to the start menu?

Currently, I have to do the following process:

1. Switch to the start menu (or any other application)
2. Go to the left side of the screen to bring up the list of running Modern UI applications.
3. Right click on the running application, select close.

It seems to me that there should be an easier way to just quit out of an application and let the OS take you back to whatever happens to be running underneath. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the top corner of the Metro App (so a litle hand will appear on the mouse pointer) and drag it to the bottom of the screen. It will force it to close.