# Closing metro apps in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

I am testing Windows 8 to see if I like it or not.  I am using Internet Explorer.  Now when I am finished using it how do I close out of it?  I don't see a close button/icon anywhere.

Comment: I have read that Alt+F4 works.  But I guess Windows is trying to implement a new system where they basically hibernate until W8 has realized you're done with it for now or something.

Comment: @nerdwaller And it would almost work if they would not stack and clutter up the top-left task-switcher charm.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty crappy system @mtone - I need to fire it up in a VBox to give it a shot.  Or at least a very confusing system.

Comment: I am running mine in VirtualBox to see if it is even worth getting.