# Can I remove apps from the "open apps" list on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager, alt-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

in windows 8 when you swipe from the left edge you can rotate through "open apps".  is there a way to remove apps from that rotation without rebooting?

"killing" the app/process in Task Manager doesn't seem to do the job.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: So you want to edit the list but leave them running/suspended (doesn't make sense, unless I'm misreading the question)? If you simply want to close them, look here: [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](http://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

Answer (score 2):

You can either middle click the thumbnail with your mouse or right click and select **Close** to close Windows Modern Applications.

If you are on a touch device, you can open the application, then drag from the top of the application downward to the bottom.  Or, if you don't want to open the application, you can open the task list, touch and hold the application you want to close/remove, then drag it to the bottom of the screen.

For further details, see [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

Comment: middle click != touch screen??? sorry for my crude response... im on a tablet. no keyboard except "on-screen"...