# How to automatically end the process when Windows 8 Modern UI apps are closed?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, resource-usage

When Metro/Modern UI applications are closed, they are not actually removed from memory; they are still running in a 'Suspended' state. This clutters up the Task Manager considerably, and is very annoying when I need to use it.

Is there any way to automatically end the process when a Metro app is closed, instead of sending it to the 'Suspended' state?

Comment: Also see [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](http://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app) Unless you specifically close the app, I don't think there's any way to change Win8's in-built process management and do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are closing an App. To exit, if you go back to the Start Screen or open another App, the discussed App would not be removed from memory. To quit you are supposed to drag the App (from the top) to the bottom of the screen.

An alternate way is to quit an App from the Multi-tasking side-bar

[image]

Comment: Does that actually remove it from memory, or does it just Suspend it like the other ways of closing apps?

Comment: It removes it from memory. I just had a check on my task manager

Comment: Suspending is what happens when you alt-tab.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

If you have a keyboard I prefer the old nice **ALT + F4** method. 
Faster than going back or using the sidebar.