# How do you exit fullscreen mode?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

I've opened fullscreen mode in Internet Explorer or Chrome on the Desktop. How do I exit out of it again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### If you have a USB keyboard

Simply press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

#### If you have a touch or type cover

Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> is [the equivalent](http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US/support/hardware-and-drivers/touch-cover-typing) for <kbd>F11</kbd>.

#### If you have no keyboard

Press and hold (your finger) anywhere within the page to reveal the context menu. This pops open the top navigation elements as well and allows you to exit fullscreen mode.

Comment: How do you make names of keyboard keys display inside boxes? I like that.

Comment: @Dan: Use the <kbd> tag (as in, "<kbd>Key Name</kbd>"). Also see [here](http://superuser.com/editing-help). You can always edit a question/answer to take a look at the code, but be sure *not* to save to prevent inadvertent editing.

Comment: Press and hold works for IE but in Chrome it doesn't show the menu so doesn't help. In Chrome, drag a finger to the top of the screen to show the exit popup.

Answer (score 4):

Drag your finger to the upper right corner and an exit full screen (F11) will appear for you to click on.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox click the upper left corner. It's quite precise so I clîck it a few times to get it.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is not asking about Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 8, if you are using the Internet explorer tile, you will have to either use the <kbd>windows</kbd> button or drag your mouse into the bottom or top left corners of the screen to reveal the application switcher or home screen.

You may also try just switching to another application if you want to keep it open by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try starting browsing from a File Manager view. Just type something in the address bar to replace "My Documents" with like http://www.google.com and hit enter.
IE will take over the window in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that different apps act differently, and the behavior is state dependent.

I posted my findings here; 
[How do I exit a Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app/835111#835111)
windows 8 - How do I exit a Modern UI app? - Super User

Answer (score -1):

I looked-up on other discussions and found exact solution after my personal experiment.

1. go charm from right screen by gesture -> setting -> change PC setting
2. turn on different type of on-screen keyboard by "keyboard" in "ease of access"
3. enjoy the "F11" in front of you to turn off full screen mode
4. swipe from left screen to send back IE or other program stuck in full screen mode then use the F11 key.