# Closing IE and other metro apps on touch screen

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, modern-ui

I'm trying to configure a device for a client who wants to use metro apps on a touch screen. The problem I'm running into at the moment is that the interface for some of these metro apps is not intuitive for touch screens at all. (Though isn't that kind of the point of metro?) My biggest issue is that the button to close the IE11 metro app is hidden in the top menu bar, which only appears on mouse hover, and that is obviously not possible in a touch-only setup. Closing the last tab also just launches a new empty tab, keeping the user trapped in IE hell until they find a mouse to make the close button appear.

Has anyone found windows/ie settings to figure out how to close IE?

Thanks.

EDIT: I see other posts about not having touch capabilities, and my issue is the opposite. I do not want to have to rely on a mouse and/or keyboard. This is a 57" display, so dragging the app from top to bottom is not super practical. I am basically hoping for a settings configuration that will provide an on-screen button or practical touch gesture to take me back to the start screen.

Comment: Why can't you just drag the apps down from the top edge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I exit a Modern UI app?](http://superuser.com/questions/335473/how-do-i-exit-a-modern-ui-app)

Comment: @Karan I've addressed the differences between my issues and the link you posted, and clarified what kind of solution I am looking for.

Comment: The button in question does not even actually end the process of the application in question it only hides the window.  **The only way to actually close a Modern UI application is the drag and drop operation.**  The only way to display the close button is not be using a touch device and have a mouse and keyboard detected.  This will change in Windows 10, with Windows 8.1, its not going to change.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't really need it to shut down the application. I just need to return to the start screen without a gesture 3+ feet across a screen.

Comment: Use the left edge method then as mentioned in the answer to that question. If all you need to do is return to the start screen, why can't you simply open the right charm and click the start button, or swipe in from the left to display the app switcher and click the start button?

Comment: I am not sure what to tell you.  There is no other way except the hand gestures which can be perform by touch or a mouse.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok. Disappointing to hear, but thank you for the confirmation.